# Is there a way to make an array of arrays? Java

Tags: java, arrays

OK so I created a method and I actually need it to return two different values. Two different arrays. Now the only way I think I could do this is by putting the values into an array. That didn't work. This was because I was initializing improperly. Now I have no clue if what I'm trying to do is possible. Or if it is I don't know how to do it and I would like some assistance. Below is what I tried doing:

```
double[] average = {averagevalues, averagepi};
and
double[] average = new double[2];
average[0] = averagevalues;
average[1] = averagepi;
```

Comment: double[][] fb = {f, b}; Changes are that you're doing something else wrong, before you need this

Comment: [Many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+array+of+arrays&oq=java+array+of+arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Example 1: `Double[][] arr1 = { array1, array2, array3, ... };`

Example 2: `Double[][] arr2 = new Double[][] { array1, array2, array3 ...};`

Answer (score 0):

```
String[][] arrays = { array1, array2, array3, array4, array5 };
```